# Gamification and punishment

Tags: design, gamification

StackExchange is a website that uses gamification. I am curious if punishment is a suitable method in gamification.

I recently posted a question on this site on how to improve my survey about UX and gamification.
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/87320

I checked yesterday. It was flagged and I had no notification prior to that, and no way to respond to the flagged post, and boy was I surprised. Thus, I lost all reputation points that I had gained. How does this make a person feel after something like this happens. A one strike and you're out certainly does not make for a good user experience. Is there a better way to handle situations like this?

Comment: It takes five votes to get your question knocked out. So it might be more accurate to say "five strikes and you're out".

Answer (score 2):

### Consequences encourage thoughtful contributions

Taking a negative hit encourages users to do one of three things:

1. Improve the answer or question to reclaim their glory
2. Delete it to remove the negative impact to their rep (and avoid further damage)
3. Quit the site

### Thoughtful contributors make a healthier community

For points 1 & 2, it's a win for the community (assuming the down votes are a legitimate indication of quality).

For point 3, it could be good or bad.

- Good if an un-knowledgeable or damaging user leaves.
- Bad if a good user leaves because they can't handle criticism.

Ultimately, it's probably good either way: A user who can't handle criticism probably isn't the right user for this format.

Comment: Unfortunately, options 1 and 2 are not possible on this site. Damage has been done with no way to reclaim the points or to fix any misunderstandings.

Comment: Is it good UX to allow a user to fail, and have no method of undoing their actions? Does not seem like a gamification design or UX design heuristic.

Comment: Apparently, I'm not familiar with the circumstances of your post. A problem question is usually placed on hold or moved to another site. In most cases, the negative feedback on SE sites is very productive.

Comment: Interesting that this is the first time I have ever received an email notification from this site alerting me of new comments. Seems like a more thoughtful human-centered process would have been to notify the user that someone had flagged your post, giving you an opportunity to accomplish option 1 or 2.